# Add suneditor css file with symfony webpack-encore

Tags: symfony, webpack-encore, suneditor

I'm trying to ad `suneditor` to a `symfony` project using `webpak-encore` , I have created a js file

`htmlEditor.js`

with this code

```
import SUNEDITOR from 'suneditor'
import 'suneditor/dist/css/suneditor.min.css'
import plugins from 'suneditor/src/plugins'

const editor = SUNEDITOR.create((document.getElementById('appbundle_popup_description') || 'appbundle_popup_description'),{
    // All of the plugins are loaded in the "window.SUNEDITOR" object in dist/suneditor.min.js file
    // Insert options
    // Language global object (default: en)
    //lang: SUNEDITOR_LANG['en'],
    height: 400,
    plugins: plugins,
    buttonList: [
        ['undo', 'redo'],
        ['font', 'fontSize', 'formatBlock'],
        ['paragraphStyle', 'blockquote'],
        ['bold', 'underline', 'italic', 'strike', 'subscript', 'superscript'],
        ['fontColor', 'hiliteColor', 'textStyle'],
        ['removeFormat'],
        '/', // Line break
        ['outdent', 'indent'],
        ['align', 'horizontalRule', 'list', 'lineHeight'],
        ['table', 'link', 'image', 'video', 'audio' /** ,'math' */], // You must add the 'katex' library at options to use the 'math' plugin.
        /** ['imageGallery'] */ // You must add the "imageGalleryUrl".
        ['fullScreen', 'showBlocks', 'codeView'],
        ['preview', 'print'],
        ['save', 'template']
    ]
});
```

then I've included an entry in `webpack.config.js`

```
.addEntry('htmlEditor', './assets/js/htmlEditor.js')
```

and I've included the files at the view file

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ parent() }}
    {{ encore_entry_link_tags('htmlEditor') }}
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    {{ encore_entry_script_tags('htmlEditor') }}
{% endblock %}
```

and then the js file ins included but not the css file, how can I include the css file ?

Comment: Did you install the assets? Do the assets exist in `node_modules`? did you run your build script? (`yarn dev` for me). Do you get any console errors in the browser?

Comment: yes , the assets exists on `node_modules` and yarn dev is executed and the output file is generated

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.
I have a solution for waiting a better solution.
Invcude the CDN in your html after the block javascript in your html head
`<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/suneditor@latest/dist/css/suneditor.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Better solution
copy the files
`suneditor/src/assets/css/suneditor-contents.css` for the editing part
and
`suneditor/src/assets/css/suneditor.css` for your view
After import in your app.js
`import '../assets/suneditor-contents.css'`
and for your back
import '../assets/suneditor.css'